# How can I have one buffered channel and multiple readers without producing a deadlock?

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock, channel

> FATAL Error All go routines are asleep. Deadlock.

This is what I tried. I am calling `wg.Done()`. What is missing?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

func sender(wg *sync.WaitGroup, cs chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i)
        cs <- i
    }
}

func reciever(wg *sync.WaitGroup, cs chan int) {
    x, ok := <-cs
    for ok {
        fmt.Println("Retrieved" + strconv.Itoa(x))
        x, ok = <-cs
        if !ok {
            wg.Done()
            break
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    cs := make(chan int, 1000)
    wg.Add(1)
    go sender(wg, cs)
    for i := 1; i < 30; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go reciever(wg, cs)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(cs)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to close channel before `wg.Wait`.
All your receivers are waiting for data from channel. That's why you have deadlock.
You can close channel at `defer` statement of `sender` function.
Also you need to `wg.Done()` if the first attempt of receiving from channel was unsuccessful (because channel already closed)

http://play.golang.org/p/qdEIEfY-kl

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things:

1. You need to close the channel once sender is completed.
2. In receiver, range over channel
3. Don't need to add 1 to wait group and call Done in sender

Please refer to http://play.golang.org/p/vz39RY6WA7